# LinkedIn share button is not aligned with its count area

Tags: linkedin-api

Does anyone have an idea why the LinkedIn share button is not aligned with its own count box?

I am not meaning aligning it with other share buttons like Facebook or Twitter.

The LinkedIn share button is not aligned with its own counter box.

Here: http://www.bbi.net.br/galeria/gal1.html

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue, diving a little deeper with firebug I found that I had a style on an anchor which was causing the issue. To fix it add:

```
.IN-widget a { 
    font-size: 100%;
    color: inherit;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, though i didn't understand how this worked since I couldn't find any anchor element among LinkedIn plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Please to check what  is the version you are using for jQuery. Since LinkedIn Button is also using a jQuery Library, your own library may cause a conflict.  Try to make your jQuery the most up to date.

Maybe helpful :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388054/linkedin-button-goes-to-the-end-bottom-of-the-page

Good luck.